# How to display all columns associated with duplicate emails in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, filter, duplicates

I've done some research on looking for a way to filter duplicate emails so all columns display the data associated with these duplicate emails, but can't find an answer to help me with this.

I currently have data pulled using the following code:

```
SELECT
    Email, COUNT(Email) AS dup_count

FROM
    [cem_farmers_masterinvitelist].[dbo].InviteList

GROUP BY
    Email

HAVING
    (COUNT(Email) > 1)

Order by Email
```

It then gives me *xxxxxx* amount of rows. I then want to be able to pull any data (columns) that are associated with these duplicate emails -and just the duplicates.

```
SELECT * FROM [marks_party_MasterInvite] .[dbo].[InviteList]
WHERE
    Email in(Select Email FROM [marks_party_MasterInvite].[dbo].[InviteList] GROUP BY Email HAVING COUNT(Email)>1)
```

I know I am doing something wrong, because the row count doesn't match.

So any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks guys,

Comment: count should be at least 2x of the select statement... if you want to know real # of duplicate records SUM the Counts...

Comment: @Borik `HAVING COUNT(Email) > 1` _is_ at least 2 rows.

Comment: Yes that my point that Row Count in First statement will be at least 2x less then row count in Second Statement, depending on number of Dupes per email.

Comment: @Borik use username with @ prefix to notify recipient of your message. I see what you're saying now, I think. But the op didn't want the count as a result... The count was just a means to identify which rows had duplicate rows, so he could then get those rows. I think! ;-)

Comment: Those row counts probably don't match because you've run your queries against two different invite lists from two different databases.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use window functions.  The following adds the count to each row.  Then you can use a `where` filter to get all the columns:

```
SELECT il.*
FROM (select il.*, count(*) over (partition by email) as cnt
      from [cem_farmers_masterinvitelist].[dbo].InviteList
     ) il
where cnt > 1
Order by Email
```

The counts don't match because when you fetch every row, you are going to get duplicates.  In the first query, you are getting distinct emails.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, hoping you don't mind answering some questions for me about this?  Is this "syntactic sugar" for a join on the `SELECT ... COUNT .. GROUP BY` or is it actually doing something different under the hood? In which case, does (or can) it perform better?  Is this syntax DBMS specific or "standard" SQL?

Comment: @Sepster . . . In my experience, window functions are generally better optimized than the equivalent aggregation/join function.  Of course, you can test and see if this is the case on your data on your system.  The window functions are standard SQL.  You appear to be using SQL Server, and they have been present since SQL Server 2005.

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time to give me the info.  I've only seen this syntax in passing here and there, and assumed it was only for very complex/unusual situations that the "basic" stuff couldn't handle easily in a single query (ie, I assumed it would allow single operations that could only previously be handled eg procedurally).  I'll look into it more, thanks again!

Comment: I Don't see how the result set will be different from what he has now?

Answer (score 0):

Join the source table, to the knowledge you just generated about your source:

```
SELECT *
FROM [cem_farmers_masterinvitelist].[dbo].InviteList src

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Email, COUNT(Email) AS dup_count

    FROM
        [cem_farmers_masterinvitelist].[dbo].InviteList

    GROUP BY
        Email
) qDupes
ON qDupes.email = src.email AND qDupes.dup_count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Row count will be different, if you want to get count of all dupe records involved, you can use ***WITH rollup ***, witch will total the number for you... This number should match the row number of second Query...

```
SELECT
    Email, COUNT(Email) AS dup_count
FROM
    [cem_farmers_masterinvitelist].[dbo].InviteList
GROUP BY
    Email WITH ROLEUP
HAVING
    (COUNT(Email) > 1)
Order by Email
```